# Inserting a sentence into search trees

Tags: data-structures, strings, search-trees

Let's say you have the following sentence: "This is my first cs question posted here". How would I go about inserting the sentence into a search tree. Do I assign each word a number value and perform the insertions based on those?

Comment: Trees usually work with arbitrary ordered domains. In this case, the exercise probably asks you to use lexicographic order. But you know better than us the context of this problem.

Comment: That actually makes sense. I mean I had to look up the word lexicographic since we've never used it before, but once I watched a YouTube video on it, I should be able to knock this  out now. Thanks!

Comment: This question is underspecified; there are infinitely many mappings to numbers, how are we to know which make sense to you?

Answer (score 1):

Search trees of various sorts can work with an *arbitrary* ordered domain, as all they rely on is a comparison function which is assumed to satisfies the axioms of a complete order:

1. If $a < b$ and $b < c$ then $a < c$.
2. Exactly one of $a < b$, $a = b$, $a > b$ (shorthand for $b < a$) holds.

In your case, you're probably meant to use the *lexicographic* order on strings. In this order, $x < y$ if:

1. Either $x$ and $y$ first differ in the $i$th symbol, and $x_i < y_i$;
2. Or $x$ is a prefix of $y$.

Symbols are probably compared in ASCII order in your case.